QML component's property x is not updated in property animation
I am using a horizontal line (HighLighter) that comes under the text of the button pressed with property animation effect.
The problem is that, when I specify the default/initial property x of HighLighter component using expression (types.width/2-width/2), the animation starts from position x specified by the expression everytime, no matter what's the current location of HighLighter component. Specifying immediate (constant) value of x yields no issue.
HighLigher blueprint
Item {
    id: root
    property var moveTo
    property alias move : move

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "#55884b"
        PropertyAnimation
        {
            id: move
            target: root
            property: "x"
            duration: 100
            to: root.moveTo
        }
    }
}

main.qml file
HighLighter
    {
        id: highLighter
        x: types.width/2-width/2
        y: footerBar.y+ labelTypes.y + labelTypes.height*1.8
        z: 2
        width: root.highlighterWidth
        height: 2
        moveTo: highlighterMoveTo
    }

Java Script Code
var selected=["true", "false", "false", "false"]
var tempX

function returnImg(root, app, arr)
{
    if(root.area.containsMouse)
    {
        if(selected[arr]==="false")
        {
            app.highlighterWidth=root.label.width
            tempX=root.x+(root.width)/2-(app.highLighter.width)/2
            app.highlighterMoveTo= tempX
            app.highLighter.move.start()
        }
    }
}


Please provide a minimal reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

As an aside, your moveTo property is declared as var. You should avoid that if you know the actual type. If you want it to be an int or a real, use that type instead of var. The main problem with var is that it won't automatically emit a Changed signal when its value is modified, so bindings won't work.

Update: When I specify the 'x' property to current position after animation is finished, it works.
move.onFinished:{ JS.updateX() }
where JS.updateX() updates its x to current position.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-behavior.html
